# Adding Character to All Rows Returned from a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to insert an hyphen in the middle of a column to all the rows of a table.  I'm pretty sure that there is a built-in function for this.

How can I specify where I want the hyphen to be placed within the column?

Comment: For example, I have the month and date listed as mmdd.  I want to place a hyphen between the month and days.

Comment: I hope that's just an example and you don't really have dates stored as strings...

Comment: This is actually being used in reporting services.  This is the date label for the parameters.

Comment: Can you give more insight to the columns and where you're wanting to put this hyphen?

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: What is the data type for your column?

Comment: I changed it a bit.  It was originally an integer, and I converted it:
  substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),date_value), 5, 4)  AS MonthYearLabel from
 table_name

Comment: So where are you wanting to insert a '-'?  Or, rephrase, if you wanted to `Select` that column in a way to come up with your desired result, how would you do that?

Comment: @user3109653: Was it actually an integer or was it a date/timestamp that you're treating as an integer. It makes a difference.

Comment: It was an integer.  I believe there is a function that allows us to add characters to a string when running a query.  Isn't there?

Comment: Siyual, I want to add a '-' between the mm and the dd

Comment: Wait... are you wanting to update the table or just insert a '-' in your `Select`?

Comment: What if the column is null or less than the position you want to place the hyphen at?

Comment: I don't want to update the table.  I just want to return the - in the query results.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (MMDD_INT INT, MMDD_CHAR VARCHAR(4))
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
 VALUES 
        (1201, '1201'),
        (1110, '1110'),
        (910 , '0910'),
        (101,  '0101')
```

### Query

```
SELECT   LEFT(RIGHT('0'+CAST(MMDD_INT AS VARCHAR(4)), 4),2)
         + '-' + RIGHT(CAST(MMDD_INT AS VARCHAR(4)),2)   AS  Int_Column

        ,LEFT(MMDD_CHAR, 2) + '-'+ RIGHT(MMDD_CHAR, 2)   AS  Char_Column

FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Int_Column ║ Char_Column ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 12-01      ║ 12-01       ║
║ 11-10      ║ 11-10       ║
║ 09-10      ║ 09-10       ║
║ 01-01      ║ 01-01       ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```